# appearance of my GUI in several OS

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, qt-designer

I would like to check the appearance of my GUI while coding, for several OS where it should be distributed.

How can I do ?

The problem is that the ‘previsualisation’ proposed by QT Designer is very different from the appearance of the distributed release. I even have spots in tabs that appear with same font and size in ‘previsualisation’ but have different sizes on Windows... I work with: python 3.5, a GUI designed with QT Designer, developed on mac OS 10.11 and shared with Windows 7 and Windows 10 systems (installed with a recent pyinstaller)

Comment: Have you tried running the QT Designer on these target OSes? Does it show the UI the same way as the running code does on these platforms? If so, is having VMs with the target OSes handy, with shared folders and QT Designer running, an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. For the moment, I developed a ui file for each OS and test the appearance "for real". That's awkward and, moreover, in a given ui file, some strings that have exactly the same apparent properties in Qt Designer may appear differently in the final release

Answer (score 2):

The preview uses some approximation of the final style drawn completely by Qt, but the style used "for real" in most platform plug-ins either employs real, native widgets, or emulates them asking for theme parts straight from the machine where it's running. So, it's not possible to have a completely faithful preview unless you use a style that is always drawn completely by Qt (such as Fusion).

Long story short: to see how your application will really look on different platforms you'll have to test it "for real".